# Evaluating Determinant (answer check)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$$\begin{vmatrix} a-x& b & c\\1& -x& 0\\0& 1& -x \\\end{vmatrix} $$

I did

$$(a-x) \begin{vmatrix} -x& 0\\1&-x\end{vmatrix}-b\begin{vmatrix} 1& 0\\0&-x\end{vmatrix}+c\begin{vmatrix} 1& -x\\0&1\end{vmatrix}$$

I got $$ax^2-a-x^3+x+bx+c+cx$$

But the answer in the book is $$-x^3+ax^2+bx+c$$

Is the answer simplified or am I doing it incorrectly?

Comment: It's fine. Would have been a little shorter expanding by the first column.

Comment: @Bernard But it's incorrect

Comment: @JohnDoe: I obtain the same result with the first column.

Comment: Remember, multiplication by $0$ yields $0$.

Comment: @Bernard The answer from the book _is_ correct. But OP's attempt is not - there is an extra $-a+x+cx$ term.

Comment: Oh! I se. I read too fast and confused the book answer and the O.P.'s answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite - you seem to have evaluated some of the determinants for the $2\times 2$ matrices incorrectly. Your method for expanding the $3\times 3$ matrices is fine. But note $$\begin{vmatrix} -x& 0\\1&-x\end{vmatrix}=(-x)(-x)-(0)(1)=x^2\\\begin{vmatrix} 1& -x\\0&1\end{vmatrix}=(1)(1)-(-x)(0)=1$$
This will get rid of the extra $-a$, $+x$ and $+cx$ terms.

Answer (score 2):

First the solution in the book is correct. In the future you can use something similar to the following to check: [Woflram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant(matrix%7B%7Ba-x,%20b,%20c%7D,%20%7B1,%20-x,0%7D,%7B%200,1,-x%7D%7D)).

It looks like you did something wrong with your expansion. Remember:

$$\det \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} = ad - bc.$$

You should have: 
$$(a-x)(x^2) -b(-x) + c$$

Comment: That's not different from the final  O.P.'s answer.

Comment: @Bernard I suspect you're misreading. OP's answer is $$ax^2-a-x^3+x+bx+c+cx$$ Which is different to this.

Comment: @JohnDoe: You're right, I misread. For my excuse, it's getting late here!

Answer (score 2):

You expanded by the first row to get

$$(a-x) \begin{vmatrix} -x& 0\\1&-x\end{vmatrix}-b\begin{vmatrix} 1& 0\\0&-x\end{vmatrix}+c\begin{vmatrix} 1& -x\\0&1\end{vmatrix}$$

Now the first $2\times 2$ determinant equals $x^2$, the second $-x$ and the third $1$ and your expansion equals

$$(a-x)x^2+bx+c=-x^3+ax^2+bx+c$$

as expected.

Answer (score 2):

$$(a-x) \begin{vmatrix} -x& 0\\1&-x\end{vmatrix}-b\begin{vmatrix} 1& 0\\0&-x\end{vmatrix}+c\begin{vmatrix} 1& -x\\0&1\end{vmatrix}$$

$$=(a-x)\left[(-x)(-x)-1\cdot0\right]-b\left[1\cdot(-x)-0\cdot 0\right]+c\left[1 \cdot 1-0\cdot (-x) \right]$$

$$=(a-x)x^2+bx+c$$

Can you complete it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to point that you can expand by any row or column youwant, if it makes life simpler. Here, you can expand by the first column:
$$\begin{vmatrix}a-x &b&c\\1&-x&0\\0&1&-x\end{vmatrix}= (a-x)\begin{vmatrix}-x&0\\1&-x\end{vmatrix}-\begin{vmatrix}b&c\\1&-x\end{vmatrix}=(a-x)x^2-(-bx-c)=\dotsm$$